# Как правильно написать условие?

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня есть следующий запрос SQL^

```
SELECT `new_tours`.*, max(lp.price) AS max_price FROM `new_tours`
    LEFT JOIN `tours_prices` `lp` ON `new_tours`.`id` = `lp`.`tour_id`
    LEFT JOIN `currency` ON currency.code = "RUB"
    LEFT JOIN `user_wallet` ON user_wallet.user_id = new_tours.user_id
WHERE (max_price < user_wallet.balance)
GROUP BY `new_tours`.`id`
```

Результат запроса возвращает ошибку:

```
Unknown column 'max_price' in 'where clause'
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне нужно исправить запрос, чтобы он отработал без ошибки?
Заранее благодарен всем отозвавшимся.

Comment: Заменить `new_tours.*` в списке вывода на `new_tours.id`. Кстати, последние две таблицы вообще не нужны - убрать. А `LEFT JOIN` замените на `INNER`.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. Замена в select, к сожалению, не помогла. А по поводу того, чтобы убрать последние две таблицы, у меня же в условии участвует вторая таблица, мне нельзя её убирать из запроса.

Comment: *по поводу того, чтобы убрать последние две таблицы, у меня же в условии участвует вторая таблица, мне нельзя её убирать* Про вторую я ничего не говорил. Убрать надо третью и четвёртую. *Замена в select, к сожалению, не помогла.* Не верю. Или реальный запрос отличается от показанного?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте условие из where перенести в having

SELECT `new_tours`.*, max(lp.price) AS max_price FROM `new_tours`
    LEFT JOIN `tours_prices` `lp` ON `new_tours`.`id` = `lp`.`tour_id`
    LEFT JOIN `currency` ON currency.code = "RUB"
    LEFT JOIN `user_wallet` ON user_wallet.user_id = new_tours.user_id

GROUP BY `new_tours`.`id` HAVING (max(lp.price) < user_wallet.balance)